# Solving upside plot and projection problems in Geopandas and Altair

Tags: python, geopandas, altair

I'm trying to plot a multi-layered map of London using some data from the ONS.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt

# Convert the 'geometry' column to shapely geometry objects
london_wards_shp['geometry'] = london_wards_shp['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
london_wards_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(london_wards_shp, geometry='geometry')
london_wards_gpd = london_wards_gpd.set_crs(epsg=4326)
london_wards_gpd.plot()
```

That came back with an error:

```
ValueError: aspect must be finite and positive
```

I found a solution to plotting:

```
london_wards_gpd.plot(aspect=1)
```

[image]

But then I wanted to use altair to build up layers, one with the whole map of layers.

```
> london_wards_map = alt.Chart(london_wards_gpd).mark_geoshape(
>     fill=None,  # No fill
>     stroke='darkgray',  # Black stroke
>     strokeWidth=1  # Stroke width ).encode(
>     tooltip='NAME:N'  # Replace 'NAME' with the actual name of the column that contains the ward names ).properties(
>     width=800,
>     height=600 ).project(
>     type='identity' )
> 
> hackney_wards = london_wards_gpd[london_wards_gpd['DISTRICT']
> =='Hackney']
> #hackney_wards = gpd.GeoDataFrame(hackney_wards, geometry='geometry')  # Convert DataFrame to GeoDataFrame
> #hackney_wards = hackney_wards.set_crs(epsg=4326) hackney_layer = alt.Chart(hackney_wards).mark_geoshape(
>     fill='lightgray',  # No fill
>     stroke='darkgray',  # Black stroke
>     strokeWidth=1  # Stroke width ).encode(
>     tooltip='NAME:N'  # Replace 'NAME' with the actual name of the column that contains the ward names ).properties(
>     width=800,
>     height=600 ).project(
>     type='identity' )
```

london_wards_map + hackney_layer

[image]

So why is it upside down?

ot quite sure how to diagnose the projection issue here

Comment: It seems like you have found a solution to the first part of your question. Could you break the second part out into a separate question and ideally include a link to/or sample of the data?

Comment: @joelostblom Will do that happily.

Comment: I've asked the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78176517/overlaid-boundary-and-point-altair-plots-are-not-aligning I think the question should be: How do I scale back the shape polygons so that the lat, for instance, is 53.xyx rather than 53xyz...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation how to plot in a Cartesian coordinate system: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks/geoshape.html#cartesian-coordinates.

```py
alt.Chart(gdf).mark_geoshape().project(
    type='identity',
    reflectY=True
)
```

The input geometry is not projected and is instead rendered directly in raw coordinates using the `identity` projection type. You will have to define the `reflectY` as well since Canvas and SVG treats positive `y` as pointing down.

Comment: Thank you for that. I also appreciate the explanation about why it flipped with SVG and Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the first problem. Flipping the dataframe can be done like so:

## Define a function to flip the y-coordinates

```
def flip_geom(geom):
    geom_type = geom.geom_type
    if geom_type == 'Polygon':
        geom = transform(lambda x, y, z=None: (x, -y), geom)
    elif geom_type == 'MultiPolygon':
        geom = transform(lambda x, y, z=None: (x, -y), geom)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unhandled geometry type: ' + repr(geom_type))
    return geom
```

Comment: Since the solution was to flip the geometry, you might be able to use the [`reflectY` and `reflectX` projection arguments](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Projection.html) in addition to your solution of changing the data.